# Writing and reading text files on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, file-io

As a practice, I am trying to write an app similar to the built-in notes app.
But I cannot figure out how to save the **file** and display it in a `UITableView`.
Right now, I have a `UITextView` that the user can type in.  I also have a **save** button.
When the user taps the save button, I want to save it, and later have it displayed in a table view.
I am very lost so if you know of any relevant tutorials etc. it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An answer that you probably don't want to hear is "Don't use text files". You could have a look at some built in serialization strategies (plists).

Comment: @hanno - I would also add that even better than plists, use Core Data.  It's fast, efficient and more importantly, *scalable*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As noted by the commenters in the real world, you're definitely going to want to look at Core Data or some other data persistence strategy. If you're dead set on pursuing this as a learning experience, something like this should solve your problem:

```
- (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {

    // Build the path, and create if needed.
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"myTextFile.txt";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    // The main act...
    [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
}

- (NSString*)readStringFromFile {

   // Build the path...
   NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString* fileName = @"myTextFile.txt";
   NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

   // The main act...
   return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Is it better than using [NSString writeToFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) ?

Comment: hello. I got error and crash at this line :[[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to save text is using NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theText forKey:@"SavedTextKey"];
```

or, if you want to have the user name each "file" or be able to have multiple files

```
NSMutableDictionary *saveTextDict = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedTextKey"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
if (saveTextDict == nil) {
    saveTextDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

[saveTextDict setObject:theText forKey:fileName];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:saveTextDict forKey:@SavedTextKey"];
```

Comment: If all that's needed is a quick-and-dirty string saving then absolutely go for the plist approach. But if you're going to scale up at all, try and resist the temptation offered by its ease of use.